# How to remove a certain field from Splunk output

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I am trying to remove a field from Search Result after running a command in Search Head on Splunk.

[image]

However as you can see in the following command that I am trying to run I see following error. I am quite new to Splunk and not sure what I need to do. Please guide.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you to specify what you want as a result.
The **table** command should help you :

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx |top DEPARTMENT | table DEPARTMENT,count
```

This way, you should only have the **DEPARTMENT** and **count** columns.